# Creating a shiny black plastic effect

Tags: gimp, texture

I would like to create a rectangle that looks like it's made from a flat piece of shiny, polished black plastic. The kind of glossy surface that attracts fingerprints on modern electronics products - something like this:

[image: Shinny black plastic sample image]

I've made a couple of attempts using a solid black background with a white overlay with reduced opacity, but it doesn't look very good, so clearly I'm missing something.

I'm looking for guidance on techniques to achieve this effect convincingly (I will be using the GIMP for what it's worth).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following this tutorial:

http://www.suite101.com/content/make-an-easy-shiny-plastic-button-in-gimp-a104126

It is supposed to create this image:

[image]

If you then make the background black, slant (and optionally slightly curve) the line, and remove the rounded corners, then you should get an effect similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: The link does not work for me